# Appcelerator Titanium classic vs alloy

Tags: mobile, titanium, appcelerator

I am learning appcelerator titanium for mobile application development.  I have googled for tutorials and got confused. Some of tutorials were following classic way to develop app and some tutorials were  developing app with alloy way. Can anyone tell me which way is best for titanium mobile app development?

P.S if anyone can share the best tutorials of titanium mobile app development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my eyes you should prefer the alloy way. Alloy apps are usually faster. If you target multiple platforms you should use Alloy because it automatically removes all the unnecessary code when compiling for the target platform.

Additionally Alloy uses a MVC architecture, which is easier to develop and to maintain. It also provides a better infrastructure to create app-wide styles and themes.

Last but not least almost all tutorials and other sources are written for Alloy styled apps. I would definitely go with Alloy!

**Although** concerning to the StackOverflow guidelines questions for the "best" tutorial are off-topic since the they don't have a universal answer I will share some of them.

1. [A basic tutorial](http://blog.foolprooflabs.com/2014/02/first-step-appcelerator-titanium/) featuring the Alloy structure. In my opinion it has just the right amount of details to start learning.
2. [The official Trainings Lab Page.](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/td/TCD+Training+Labs) It features some rough recipes to create basic functions. It should point you in the right direction.
3. If you prefer [video tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bU2vA8mqhJ8) try this one.
4. The very basic [official quickstart page](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Quick_Start). It points to many other useful pages including the docs.
5. Last but not least two other questions I found online which discuss this topic. [Question1](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/154294/alloy-tutorials), [Question2](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/143969/alloy-mvc-examples)

Comment: Can you please share best tutorials?

Comment: I edited my answer. This should be a sufficient amount of tutorials.

Comment: Glad that I could help you. Please mark this answer as accepted when your question has been answered. This makes it easy for others to notice that your question is completed.